# missing parameter type for expanded function （scala）

Tags: scala, sbt, spark-streaming

Here's my function:

```
val valueDStream: DStream[String] = kafkaDSteam.map(record => record.value()).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify parameter types for **some** of your lambdas

```
(record: ???) => record.value()

.map((_ : ???, 1))

.reduceByKey((_ : ???) + (_ : ???))
```